# why this model fail to converge without manual weight initialization step (pytorch linear regression)

Tags: initialization, pytorch, linear-regression, gradient

I am trying to create a most simple 1 linear layer network to fit a linear regression. Just to help myself better understand how Pytorch works. However, I encountered a strange issue with the model training.

in my model’s init() method, I have to add a manual initialization step(shown below) to have the model quickly converge to my regression function. (the weight value 2, 3 are random number, I could put any value here and the model will still converge)

```
self.layer1.weight = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor([2, 3]))
```

Without this line, the model never converge, the training loss just randomly oscillates in the range of hundreds of thousands. With this line, it quickly decreases to near 1.

I have postulated that it is because default initial weight parameters were too small if I do not initialize them to be far away from zero. Then I changed the initial values and found out the convergence always work as long as I have this line, the exact value I set does not matter. I tried using debugger to step through this line and use **vars()** method to examine the attributes of **self.layer1**, the only thing changed is the weights, everything else remains the same. Could someone explain what is going on behind the scene here? Thanks.

My entire script:

```
import torch
import numpy as np

class Net(torch.nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, input_dim, output_dim):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.layer1 = torch.nn.Linear(input_dim, output_dim, bias=False)

        # the line below is the strange initialization required to 
        # have the model converge. 
        self.layer1.weight = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor([2, 3]))

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.layer1(x)
        return x

# generate data using the linear regression setup y = 5 * x1 + 3 * x2

sample_size = 10000
input_dim = 2
output_dim = 1
epoch = 30
bs = 100

data = np.random.randn(sample_size, 3)
data[:, :2] = data[:, :2] * 100
# add a normal noise term
data[:, 2] = 5 * data[:, 0] + 3 * data[:, 1] + np.random.randn(sample_size)
data = torch.Tensor(data)
train_x = data[:, :input_dim]
train_y = data[:, input_dim]

net = Net(input_dim, output_dim)
criterion = torch.nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.RMSprop(net.parameters(), lr=.01)

for i in range(epoch):

    batch = 0
    while batch * bs < train_x.shape[0]:

        batch_x = train_x[batch * bs : (batch + 1) * bs, :]
        batch_y = train_y[batch * bs : (batch + 1) * bs]

        pred_y = net.forward(batch_x)
        loss = criterion(pred_y, batch_y)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        if batch % 100 == 0:
            #print(f"{i} {batch} {loss}")
            print(net.layer1.weight)
        batch += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick note: your code does not compile, please modify this line as shown:

```
self.layer1.weight = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor([[2, 3]]))
```

I was unable to get your model to converge, regardless of weight initialization. After some experimentation, I found that lowering the batch size to one does the trick:

```
$ python main.py
Parameter containing:
tensor([[0.7388, 0.3678]], requires_grad=True)
Parameter containing:
tensor([[1.7438, 1.0657]], requires_grad=True)
Parameter containing:
tensor([[2.3338, 1.5431]], requires_grad=True)
Parameter containing:
tensor([[2.9008, 1.9784]], requires_grad=True)
Parameter containing:
tensor([[3.2375, 2.1437]], requires_grad=True)
Parameter containing:
tensor([[3.6419, 2.4014]], requires_grad=True)
Parameter containing:
tensor([[4.0652, 2.6458]], requires_grad=True)
Parameter containing:
tensor([[4.5095, 2.7628]], requires_grad=True)
Parameter containing:
tensor([[4.7711, 2.8982]], requires_grad=True)
Parameter containing:
tensor([[4.9131, 2.9768]], requires_grad=True)
Parameter containing:
tensor([[4.9887, 2.9979]], requires_grad=True)

...
```